# Couchbase Elasticsearch plugin transforming data before pushing

Tags: elasticsearch, couchbase, elasticsearch-plugin

I have two couchbase cluster and I wanted to push a merged version of the documents in the clusters to elastic search using the following ES-Couchbase plugin:http://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/server/current/connectors/elasticsearch-2.1/elastic-intro.html

I haven't been able to find any documentation regarding altering or modifying data from couchbase before it is transported to elastic search via the plugin. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's not currently possible to change data between Couchbase and Elasticsearch with the transport plugin. The goal of the plugin is to have an accurate replica of the data, so there is no ETL capability built in.

You have to create the merged version of the data in a Couchbase bucket and then replicate that bucket to Elasticsearch. Alternatively, you can use a 3rd party framework to do ETL on the data in Couchbase and send it to Elasticsearch. For example, you can use Couchbase's Apache Spark connector to stream data from the two buckets, perform any merge logic you require, and then store it in Elastic.